# Sharepoint Gantt chart - default view to always show 'today'?

Tags: sharepoint, gantt, moss

I have a gantt chart which always defaults to the start of the first bar (earliest point in time)

This is very annoying in our dashboard as I can't see where we are on this i.e. it should be dynamic based on the current date

Is there any way to change the view to have it move to show that?

I think it's sharepoint 2003 we're using.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a Gantt chart in SharePoint 2003 so I am assuming you are using 2007/2010.

What you can do is setup a filter to show only items where

End Date >= [Today]

and then base your Gantt chart on that.

*Note* - using End Date as otherwise if you had a task that started yesterday, but finished in a weeks time then it would not show 'today'

Otherwise if this doesn't work for you there are 3rd party products that allow you to have more control over the chart - *cough, blatant plug, cough* such as [Planner](http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/planner/planner-manual?p=configuration/config_period.htm).

Comment: It will be 2007 that we're using then. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I tried your suggestion which moves the view closer to where 'today' is but it strips off all the other tasks which is somewhat confusing. Alas I don't have control over the MOSS box so I wouldn't be able to implement anything like that.

Comment: "Strips off all the other tasks" - what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a calculated field that returns the max of whatever field tracks the task start date and today.
2. Set this calculated field as the start date for the Gantt chart view.

Tasks that start in the future will have their bars start at a future date.  Tasks that start in the past will all show a minimum value of today.

Answer (score -1):

The suggested solution with calculated column will not work, as calculated columns can't be used in Gannt view. View based on the proposed solution returns no start date at all.

The only working scenario seems to be the usage of [scroll to date script in content editor WP.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4571673-ae7b-4589-903f-44774a29e9a6/how-to-display-by-default-the-gantt-chart-with-todays-date?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: It would be better to add details from the link.  Link only answers are discouraged

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.